# What is the purpose of using (function ($) {...})

Tags: javascript

I have never writen vanilla js before and today I saw some code. There was a JavaScript file that started with:

```js
(function ($) {...})
```

and they had written all the code inside this function. What is the purpose of this usage? And what is the name of this usage?

Comment: It's called an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: @nullptr That's not an IIFE since it's not Immediately Invoked.

Comment: That construct on its own doesn't do anything (useful). There should be a `(jQuery)` (most likey, or any other library that uses `$`) right behind that `})` -> `(function ($) {...})(jQuery)`

Comment: @Andreas yes there was.

Comment: @AKX it's not an iife only because op was missing the invoking part lol

Comment: @nullptr yes, which makes it nothing more than a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).